# Keep Point Visible After Terrain Mesh Added - Cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, terrain

Say I am showing a point on a Cesium map: (https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML%20Point.html&label=All)

When I switch the terrain setting from WGS84 Ellipsoid to STK World Terrain Meshes the point disappears, essentially getting "covered up" by the terrain. The point is only visible from far distances.

How can I make sure that my point is always visible? That it is associated to the terrain height no matter what mode I am in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the requested point is at "zero" height, which is on the surface when there's no terrain, but is otherwise underground.  Cesium has a feature to clamp points to ground: [Here's a demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Clamp%20to%20Terrain.html&label=All).

The key line of code in this demo (applied to both the point and its label) is this one:

```
    heightReference : Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND
```

I have sometimes seen issues where if the terrain service is too slow at first, it will get the wrong height initially, but you can reload the page to fix that.